# I can use an interface in the html component but not in the typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript, api, interface

I'm using the Google Books Api in Angular. For that reason I created the following interface

```
    export interface DateBooks {
    kind:string,
    totalItems:number,
    items:Book[]
   }
   export interface Book {
   kind:string,
   id:string,
   etag:string,
   selfLink:string,
   volumeInfo: VolumeInfo[],
   saleInfo:SaleInfo,
   accessInfo:AccessInfo,
   searchInfo:SearchInfo
   }
   export interface VolumeInfo {
   title:string,
   subtitle:string,
   authors:string[],
   publisher:string,
   publisedDate:string,
   description:string,
   industryIdentifiers:IndustryIdentifiers[],
   readingModes:ReadingModes,
   pageCount:number,
   printType:string,
   categories:string[],
   maturityRating:string,
   allowAnonLogging:boolean,
   contentVersion:string,
   panelizationSummary:PanelizationSummary,
   averageRating:number,
   ratingCount:number,
   imageLinks:ImageLinks,
   language:string,
   previewLink:string,
   infoLink:string,
   canonicalVolumeLink:string
   }
   
   export interface ImageLinks {
   smallThumbnail:string,
   thumbnail:string
   }
   
   
   export interface IndustryIdentifiers{
       type:string,
       identifier:string
   }
   
   export interface ReadingModes{
       text:boolean,
       image:boolean
   }
   
   export interface PanelizationSummary{
       containsEpubBubbles:boolean,
       containsImageBubbles:boolean
   }
   
   export interface SaleInfo{
       country:string,
       saleability:string,
       isEbook:boolean
   }
   
   export interface AccessInfo{
       country:string,
       viewability:string,
       embeddable:boolean,
       publicDomain:boolean,
       textToSpeechPermission:string,
       epub:Epub,
       pdf:Pdf,
       webReaderLink:string,
       accessViewStatus:string,
       quoteSharingAllowed:boolean
   }
   
   export interface SearchInfo{
       textSnippet:string
   }
   
   export interface Epub{
       isAvailable:boolean
   }
   
   export interface Pdf{
       isAvailable:boolean
   }
```

This is  my typescript component

```
    databooks:DateBooks;
    books:Book[];
    title:string;
    constructor(private GoodreadsService:GoodreadsService) { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    getLibros(libro:string){
      this.GoodreadsService.getBooks(libro).subscribe(data=>{
        this.databooks=data;
        this.books=this.databooks.items;
      })
    
        }
```

This, the getBooks method

```
public getBooks(busqueda:string): Observable<DateBooks>{
    return this.http.get<DateBooks>(`https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${busqueda}&maxResults=40`);
```

And , this the html component

```
    <input type="text" id="namea" name="nameb" required
        minlength="4" maxlength="8" size="10" placeholder="introduzca texto" [(ngModel)]="title" (keyup)="getLibros(title) " >
        <div *ngFor="let book of books">
          <h4 class="prueba">
              <p> {{book.volumeInfo['title']}}</p>
       <p><img src={{book.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}></p>
          </h4>    
        </div>
```

So, I can use the interface without problems in the html, besides if I run and write anything in the input, the page show correctly the titles of the books, and the cover. However, I cant get only a few properties of the interface on the ts. For instance, in the subscribe data is the object that getBooks return, the I can use data.items without problems, but if I write data.item.volumeInfo Visual code say this error: Property 'volumeinfo' does not exist on type 'Book[]', but I can use without problem in the html, the I don't know howw could I fix this issue?.

Could somebody tell me what is the problem or my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Concern #1** -
*"but if I write data.item.volumeInfo Visual code say this error: Property 'volumeinfo' does not exist on type 'Book[]'"*

- That is because you are trying to access the `object property` directly inside an **array** of Books
- Example:

```
// Mock Data
const books: Books[] = [ 
   { name: 'Book 1', volumeInfo: '123' }, 
   { name: 'Book 2', volumeInfo: '457' } 
];

// This is what you are trying to do which will produce an error
// Directly accessing a property inside an array which is invalid since we are not accessing
// a mere object but we are accessing an array of object
books.volumeInfo

// What we must do to access them is through:
books[0].volumeInfo

// or through using .map, .filter, .forEach and other similar to iterate the array and access the properties inside
books.map(book => console.log(book))
books.forEach(book => console.log(book));
```

**Concern #2** - *but I can use without problem in the html*

- That is because you have iterated the array through `*ngFor="let book of books"` just like how we can iterate through `.map, .filter, and .forEach` the array of objects
- Similar to:

```
books.forEach(book => console.log(book.volumeInfo));        // 123
                                                            // 457
```

---

In Summary, if we want to access an array of objects, use `.map, .filter, .forEach or other similar` for us to get an instance to all properties under that array

Comment: your explanation has been clear, you are very nice thanks :)